# Show links depending on role's name

Tags: 7, navigation

I want to show a custom link for each role on my site. To do so, I will put PHP code in my page.tpl.php. I want to add an if statement that checks if the current user's role is equal to something, then print the link.

How can I get the current user role?

Comment: Putting PHP in page.tpl.php violates Drupal programming style, of-course the extendibility of your theme. Better way is to make a block and give permission to it through block configuration page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
global $user;
if($user->roles[1] || $user->roles[2]){
//Do Something
}
```

Comment: The code just check the user has two roles; whatever they are are, the control statement is executed.

Comment: Has either* role